# Need advice on efficiently inserting millions of time series data into a Cassandra DB

Tags: scala, cassandra

I want to use a Cassandra database to store time series data from a test site. I am using [Pattern 2 from the "Getting started with Time Series Data Modeling" tutorial](https://academy.datastax.com/resources/getting-started-time-series-data-modeling) but am not storing the date to limit the row size as a date, but as an `int` counting the number of days elapsed since 1970-01-01, and the timestamp of the value is the number of nanoseconds since the epoch (some of our measuring devices are that precise and the precision is needed). My table for the values looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE values (channel_id INT, day INT, time BIGINT, value DOUBLE, PRIMARY KEY ((channel_id, day), time))
```

I created a simple benchmark, taking into account [using asynchronity and prepared statements for batch loading instead of batches](https://lostechies.com/ryansvihla/2014/08/28/cassandra-batch-loading-without-the-batch-keyword/):

```
  def valueBenchmark(numVals: Int): Unit = {
    val vs = session.prepare(
      "insert into values (channel_id, day, time, " +
      "value) values (?, ?, ?, ?)")
    val currentFutures = mutable.MutableList[ResultSetFuture]()
    for(i <- 0 until numVals) {
      currentFutures += session.executeAsync(vs.bind(-1: JInt,
        i / 100000: JInt, i.toLong: JLong, 0.0: JDouble))
      if(currentFutures.length >= 10000) {
        currentFutures.foreach(_.getUninterruptibly)
        currentFutures.clear()
      }
    }
    if(currentFutures.nonEmpty) {
      currentFutures.foreach(_.getUninterruptibly)
    }
  }
```

`JInt`, `JLong` and `JDouble` are simply `java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Long` and `java.lang.Double`, respectively.

When I run this benchmark for 10 million values, this needs about two minutes for a locally installed single-node Cassandra. My computer is equipped with 16 GiB of RAM and a quad-core i7 CPU. I find this quite slow. Is this normal performance for inserts with Cassandra?

I already read these:

- [Anti-Patterns in Cassandra](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/architecture/architecturePlanningAntiPatterns_c.html)
- [Another question on write performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22836529/how-to-increase-the-write-performance-in-cassandra)

Are there any other things I could check?

Comment: Can you please add your JVM memory parameters in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple maths:

10 millions inserts/2 minutes ≈ 83 333,33333 inserts/sec which is great for a single machine, did you expect something faster?

By the way, what are the specs of your hard-drives ? SSD or spinning disks ?

You should know that massive insert scenarios are more CPU bound than I/O bound. Try to execute the same test on a machine with 8 physical cores (so 16 vcores with Hyper Threading) and compare the results.

Comment: They are SSDs, and if this value is great, then everything is alright. We plan to use this in a cluster later anyway. The disks are SSDs, and about the CPU cores, that makes sense. I tried it the other way round, on a small VM with two vCPUs and 4GiB of RAM and it was way slower (as I expected). After all, this performance IS more than enough for our scenarios.

Comment: Is there is any advised JVM memory parameters for such case?

Comment: if you have a lot of RAM (minimum 32G), use G1 GC config and set the JVM heap size to a big value (≥ 16gb)